# win10 does not boot after shrinking and moving main partition

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, efi

so i shrink my main win10 partition of 512mb and moved it of 512mb in order to expand my efi partition wich was too smal for dualbooting my computer. i did not touch any other partition. 
I tried fixing my efi bootloader by following this tutorial : https://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cadhs1/sln300987/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7-8-8-1-and-10-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en and it did not work.
i also tried to maualy lunch it through the boot menu.

any idea what could cause the problem??

Comment: Best bet is to restore from the image you made before trying to resize partitions.

Comment: there is no image since i use win exclusively for gaming and adobe but i would rather fix it than reinstall everything